# Find area of region $ { (x,y) : 0<y< x^2+1, 0< y < x+1, 0<x<2 } $

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I can't understand which area needs to be found here. Is it the common area which exists between x=0 and x=1?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image] 
\begin{align}
\{ (x,y) : 0<y< x^2+1\} &= A \cup C \cup G  \cup F  \cup H\\[2ex]
\{ (x,y) : 0< y < x+1\} &= C \cup E  \cup G  \cup H      \\[2ex]
\{ (x,y) : 0<x<2 \}     &= D \cup E  \cup G  \cup F  \cup J
\end{align}

The intersection is, then

$$ \{ (x,y) : 0<y< x^2+1, 0< y < x+1, 0<x<2 \} = G  $$